# reduction of each row in the table of database

Tags: php

i have a table temporary as follow as:

```
student    |      Data     |    number           
-----------|---------------|--------------
1          |   book        |      2          
1          |   book        |      5    
1          |   book        |      9     
2          |   book        |      1         
2          |   book        |      5
```

i will show reduction of column in like as output column as follow as:

```
student    |   Data        |    number      |output (number column of next row-previous line )
-----------|---------------|----------------|--------------
1          |   book        |      2         |     0
1          |   book        |      5         |     3  (result of (5-2=3)
1          |   book        |      9         |     4  (result of (9-5=4)
2          |   book        |      1         |     0
2          |   book        |      5         |     4  (result of (5-1=4)
```

how are writing of php's script is correct? because i'm confused

Comment: Please be more specific with your description and question. Right now it is hard to comprehend what you want to do.

Comment: Could you please better-describe the "reduction column"? Are you looking for something like `SELECT (number - 2) AS output FROM some_table`, or something more complicated?

Comment: What database? Edit your question and include the query (and your php code) so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: The only pattern I can make out of the data is that `output` is `number(current row) - number(previous row for current student)`.. is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you define the order of the rows?

Answer (score 1):

The following script will subtract the number from previous number for the same student. Here's how you can do it in MySQL (which doesn't support window functions.)

```
SELECT 
    t1.student, 
    t1.Data, 
    t1.number, 
    IF (t2.number IS NULL, 0, t1.number - MAX(t2.number)) as output 
FROM 
    tbl t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl t2 
ON 
    t1.student = t2.student 
    AND t1.number > t2.number 
GROUP BY 
    t1.student, t1.Data, t1.number
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ee69/1)

Comment: i'm sorry, I want to generate the output columns in the following manner: the first line is zero, the second row (the result of (5-2=3)), and so on, but it will be repeated again as early as the other students, and i have one table in database and i will show that output use SELECT

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your DBMS, so this is standard SQL:

```
select student,
       data, 
       number,
       number - lag(number,1,number) over (partition by student order by id) as output
from the_table
order by student, id
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/047c6/5)

Comment: Wow... I've never seen lag, over, or partition. Now I'm going to go look those up :)

Comment: @chrislondon: those are called "window functions" and are pretty much a common feature nowadays. Oracle has had them for ages.

Comment: sorry, i will try that sql's script in mysql, that scripts are error, please help me, another solution!

Comment: @pucca: MySQL does not support this