# Which SQL DBMSs Follow Which SQL Standards?

Tags: sql, standards

**Question**

Which SQL DBMSs support which SQL Standards?

**Back story**

So today on SO I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17067571/2200766) that didn't mention which DBMS they were using so I answered with MySQL.  To solve the problem I had to use a `JOIN`, however later another person (with 60k+ reputation :)) answered the same question using some "fancy" functions I've never heard of before.  Turns out they are "window functions".  So I looked at how to use them in MySQL only to find out MySQL doesn't support them :(  Now my faith in MySQL is shaken. I'm now wondering if MySQL is the best option for me (but that's not the question here since that would be flagged as not constructive ;))

I'm hoping for a website like [this](http://caniuse.com/#tables) which is about CSS compatibility over the different browser versions but instead a SQL compatibility over the different DMBSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site has been very handy to me over the years... http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/

And of course, wikipedia... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems